# qgis2to3 to migrate plugin from version 2 to version 3

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-2, migration

I have a plugin in QGIS 2  and I'm trying to migrate it to version 3

I downloaded the 'qgis2to3' tool

--> I installed the pip (get-pip.py) :

```
python get-pip.py
```

--> I installed qgis2to3 :

```
python pip install --user qgis2to3
```

but when I try to use the command qgis2to3 /path/to/my/plugin it retruns this error :

```
can't find '__main__' module in 'qgis2to3'
```

Comment: "didn't figure out how to use it" is too vague, you will need to explain what you tried and where you got stuck in order for anyone to help you.

Comment: @csk I edited the question and explained in details what I did

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows make sure you are running the qgis2to3 script through the OSGeo4W Shell.

Make sure you also have a few things installed through the advanced settings in the OSGeo4W installer:

Desktop:

qgis-dev

Libs:

python-future

I find it easier to just use the 2to3 script without installing it through PIP.

You can grab it using:
https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/scripts

Extract that into a location of your choice.

Then we can run the 2to3 script from the OSGeo4W console (cd to the folder you extracted the script to):

`python 2to3 C:\path_to_plugin\QGIS_Multi_Ring_Buffer`

There is a full guide at:

https://gisforthought.com/updating-a-plugin-from-qgis-2-to-qgis-3/

Comment: I got this error when I had tried with OSGEO :

 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip

Comment: You would need to install pip through the OSGeo4W installer.